# Table HTML border

Tags: html, html-table, alignment, html-email

I am having some difficulty with my HTML email template. I am new to this HTML world and it's my first email template. The fact that I cannot use `<div>` tags is really giving headache to me.

I think it would be better if you look at the screenshot. I explained there nicely what I want. Here is an image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk2gK.jpg]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Fashion Newsletter</title>
<style type="text/css" >
body {
    font: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--For Three Columns-->

<table align="center" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000" >
  <tr>
    <td width="180">
        <a href="#link">
          <img src="images/180.gif" />
        </a>
      </td>
    <td width="180">
        <a href="#link">
          <img src="images/180.gif" />
        </a>
      </td>
    <td width="180"><p class="three">
        <a href="#link">
          <img src="images/180.gif" />
        </a>
      </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I deleted the code for "Single Column" table because for single columns code is working fine. I also intentionally added `bgcolor="#000"` so that I can have a look what is happening.

Summary:

1. If you looked at the screenshot, I basically want to decrease the space between the two `<td>` tags i.e. two columns.
2. I want to remove the space that is generated at the end of the table (extreme right, black colored)

Comment: I may be wrong but, it looks like you're setting your table to be 600px and each column to be 180px. This might account for the black area between the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table width="600" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000" class="box" >
<tr>
<td width="180">
    <a href="#link">
      <img src="images/180.gif" />        </a>      </td>
<td width="180">
    <a href="#link">
      <img src="images/180.gif" />        </a>      </td>
<td width="180"><p class="three">
    <a href="#link">
      <img src="images/180.gif" />        </a>
  </p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

added a css style which you can play around with and get the look you want:

```
.box {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 2px;
padding: 2px;
width: 600px;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000066;
border-right-color: #990000;
border-bottom-color: #00FF33;
border-left-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;
In the table tag style="border-style:solid; border-width:2px 0px 2px 0px;"

Answer (score 0):

try this one. basically, make the `table` 560px wide, put 10px `td` between the images. also you may need to remove the `p` tag for the third column to avoid unwanted margin/padding.

If you want to keep the `table` 600px wide, just add 20px `td` before the first column and after the third column.

```
<table align="center" width="560" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000" >
  <tr>
    <td width="180">
        <a href="#link">
          <img src="images/180.gif" />
        </a>
      </td>
    <td width="10"></td>
    <td width="180">
        <a href="#link">
          <img src="images/180.gif" />
        </a>
      </td>
    <td width="10"></td>
    <td width="180"><a href="#link">
          <img src="images/180.gif" />
        </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```